# pandas df.sort_values() does not work for multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to sort my dataframe first for each id. Then within id, I want to sort by visitnumer.

```
in: df.sort_values(by=[('id'),'visitnumber'], ascending=[False, True])
out: df=

    id      visitnumber     
-9223372    194             
-9223372    226             
-9223372    181
```

As you can see, the sort for visitnumber did not work as visitnumber=181 is the smallest, thus should be listed first.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The syntax is `df.sort_values(['id', 'visitnumber'], ascending=[False, True])`. do note the missing `()`

Comment: @DOOM it does not work either, unfortunately!

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? What are your data types?

Comment: @MattR for id=int64 and for visitnumber=int64

Comment: You are not assigning `df` to the result of `df.sort_values()`. Otherwise, use `inplace=True` argument.